# Парсер выводит неверное значение

Tags: php, json, request

json ответ от сайта:

```
{ "title": "Аккумлятор на сити коко 60v20Ah", "price": "6020", "image": "https://apollo-olx.cdnvideo.ru:443/v1/files/yzyh3hgf2q5c3-UZ/image;s=1000x652" }
```

Функция приёма ответа:

```
function parseItem($id, $url, $a) {
        $url = str_replace("d/", "ad/", $url);
        function utf8ize($mixed) {
            if (is_array($mixed)) {
                foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
                    $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value);
                }
            } elseif (is_string($mixed)) {
                return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
            }
            return $mixed;
        }
        $page = json_decode(utf8ize(request("https://api.queryhost.ovh/parser.php?url=".$url."&country=OLX-UA")), true);
        $itemd = [5, 6, 0, $id, time()];
        $itemd[] = $page['price']; // значение суммы из strong, работает
        $itemd[] = $page['title']; // название, за него переживаю больше всего, неудобно сделано
        $itemd[] = $page['image']; // meta с ссылкой на картинку, работает точно
        $itemd[] = getUserAddress($id); // факт.адрес объявления, больше address на странице нет, должен пахать
        $itemd[9] = getUserAddress($id); // ФИО
        $itemd[10] = getUserAddress($id); // Номер
        $itemd[11] = getUserAddress($id); // Адрес
        $itemd[] = 'block';
        return $itemd;
    }
```

И функция ответа от бота телеграм:

```
botSend([
                        ' <b>Парсинг</b>',
                        '',
                        ' Название: <b>'.$itemd[6].'</b>',
                        ' Стоимость: <b>'.beaCash($itemd[5]).'</b>',
                    ], chatAlerts());
                    break;
                }
```

Получаю ответ:

```
 Название: Аккумлятор на сити коко 60v20Ah
 Стоимость: 0
```

UPD. Функция beaCash:

```
function beaCash($v) {
    return number_format($v, 0, '', 0).'';
}
```

Comment: содержимое `beaCash` мы угадать должны? Собрать нормальный объект вы в состоянии,  а не писать `item[0], item[1], item[n]`?

Comment: @ArchDemon я добавил функцию beaCash :(

Comment: посмотрите на передаваемые аргументы в `number_format`. особенно на последний

Comment: посмотрел, ничего такого не вижу

Comment: Ну и что передаётся последним аргументом в `number_format`?

Comment: нуу.... я  не знаю

Comment: Попробуйте начать с прочтения документации

Comment: @ArchDemon так, последний это разделитель тысяч да?

Comment: Он самый. Аргумент типа строка. А вы что передаёте?

Comment: я передаю то что нужно вроде @ArchDemon

Comment: Ты там НОЛЬ передаешь, а не "то что нужно".

Comment: @u_mulder а что нужно? :(

Comment: @u_mulder я там передавал и ' ', и ',' в общем много чего

Comment: Нужно в функции `beaCash` сделать `var_dump($v)` и увидев 0 или null - понять откуда он там взялся.